# How to scrape nested text between tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I found a website using the following HTML structure somewhere:

```html
...
<td>
  <span>some span text</span>
  some td text
</td>
...
```

I'm interested in retrieving the `"some td text"` and **not** the `"some span text"` but the `get_text()` method seems to return all the text as `"some span textsome td text"`. Is there a way to get **just** the text inside a certain element using BeautifulSoup?

Not all the `td`s follow the same structure, so unfortunately I cannot predict the structure of the resulting string to trim it where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element has a `name` attribute, which tells you the type of tag, e.g. `div`, `td`, `span`. In the case there is no tag (bare content), it will be `None`.

So you can just use a simple list comprehension to filter out all the tag elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<td>
  <span>some span text</span>
  some td text
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('td')
text = [c.strip() for c in content if c.name is None and c.strip() != '']
print(text)
```

This will print:

> ['some td text']

after some cleaning of newlines and empty strings.

If you wanted to join up the content afterwards, you could use `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(text))
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the `name` attribute trick, thanks!